# What font is Firefox using for `system-ui`?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, css, web-fonts, html

I'm trying to work out what font my Firefox is using for its `system-ui` CSS  property value, which is used on pages that specify `system-ui` in their font stack (specifically, I first saw it on my website [here](https://ato.pxeger.com), but I don't think that's too relevant). Here is a screenshot:

[image: A font demonstration containing a large variety of characters]

It does not appear to match *any* font on my computer at all (I literally searched for all `ttf`, `otf`, and `woff` files, and none match).

I have also tried in vain on websites like WhatTheFont and Identifont.

I feel, however, it must be a reasonably common web font that is freely available, because of its usage.

---

If you know some more about software and stuff, the following information might be useful:

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition 90.0b6-1 on Arch Linux with KDE Plasma 5.22.1-1 and X11 xorg-server 1.20.11-1.

This screenshot came from this URL (which I constructed myself to better see the font): `` data:text/html,<p style="font-size:10em;font-family:system-ui;overflow-wrap:break-word">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!"$%^&*()-_=+[{]};:'@%23~,<.>/?|` ``

Comment: Does the Inspector tab not tell you? It has a Fonts sub-tab that shows the actual, computed font in use for whatever element you’re inspecting.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah, thanks: it says it is Cantarell, which it seems to be, but then it seems it's a slightly different version Cantarell to the one on Google Fonts for some reason??

Comment: I would imagine this is the standard GNOME version embedded in Firefox itself, while the Google Fonts one is slightly altered.